# Deleting trac tickets created since a certain date until today

Tags: trac

i left my trac create ticket open, and cheked it out several weeks later and it was filled with junk people filled in to give their companies links for seo. **I want to ge rid of every ticket created since a certain date until today.**

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove a ticket using the `trac-admin` command.  To delete (for example) tickets 100-140, try using a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ticket=100
end_ticket=140

while [ $ticket -le $end_ticket ]; do
    trac-admin /path/to/env ticket remove $ticket
    ticket=$(( $ticket + 1 ))
done
```

You can also delete tickets directly out of the database, but that's a lot more error-prone.

Unfortunately, you need shell access to the server hosting your Trac instance to use the `trac-admin` command.  If you don't have access, this becomes much trickier.

Comment: Thank you! i have access to everything yes

Comment: At least in trac 0.12.5 it is `ticket remove` instead of `ticket delete`

Comment: after the need to create near 200 tickets... i'm kinda in love with you @bta :P